# Adding brand new columns to an existing table

Tags: sql, database

How big of a no-no is this in the database world? Suppose I launch my application then later decide I'd like to record additional attributes about an entity. Is adding a brand new column to an existing table to be avoided at all cost? Or is it no big deal?

Comment: @Strawberry: It's not obvious to someone who's just starting out with databases. SO welcomes all level of developers; not everyone posting here has the same experience.

Comment: I've done it like 100 times already, in so many applications. When you deploy to production for the first time you don't know what the client will like to do next month, quarter, or year. Everything ends up changing.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a column in MySQL (or most any modern DB) is straightforward. You use a command like

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD [COLUMN] column_name column_definition [FIRST|AFTER existing_column];
```

[(reference)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html).

Note that if you add a column to an existing table with a substantial number of data rows, the operation may take some time. Practice in a test environment first and plan for downtime in the production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Should adding a new column be avoided at all costs?  Well, no.

Should adding a new column be avoided?  Well, yes.

First, it is an expensive operation, normally requiring rewriting an entire table.  For efficiency reasons, it is often a better idea to create a new table and load the data into the new table.

Second, a new column is often a problem of something wrong with a data model.  Hopefully the structure of the database is pretty well understood before the application is finished.

Does this mean that adding a column is always bad?  Of course not.  New things come along, something small might have been missed, some inconsistency might arise.  However, it should not be done casually because it might suggest bigger problems with the underlying data model.  It should also be done carefully if there are large volumes of data in the live system.